# I have a Tecra A4 laptop. How can I ensure I have the latest graphics driver for it?

Tags: video, drivers, laptop

I have a Tecra A4 laptop. How can I ensure I have the latest graphics driver for it?

According to http://alatest.com/reviews/laptop-reviews/toshiba-tecra-a4-s211/po3-32484355,30/#details, I have a ATI Mobility Radeon X600/NVIDIA GeForce Go 6600

When I go to System > Administration > Additional Drivers, it does a check and says "No Proprietary Drivers are in use on this system" with a black list box and a disabled Enable button.

Comment: Might be useful to give a little more information, such as the graphics chipset in the laptop (ATI/AMD, NVIDIA, or Intel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ATI Mobility Radeon X600, then you cannot use proprietary drivers, as AMD discontinued support of this card.

If you have NVIDIA GeForce Go 6600, then you can install drivers via System > Administration > Additional Drivers.

Post output of **lspci** command for sure.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you keep your system up-to-date via Update Manager (under System > Administration > Update Manager) then the latest tested graphics drivers will automatically be installed.

If you have an NVIDIA or ATI/AMD graphics card, then you can opt-in to the manufacturer-supplied drivers by going to System > Administration > Additional Drivers.

Updated from your question:

> When I go to System > Administration > Additional Drivers, it does a check and says "No Proprietary Drivers are in use on this system" with a black list box and a disabled Enable button.

If this is the case, your laptop may have an integrated Intel GMA chipset, which does not require proprietary drivers (and you're already up-to-date). I googled around and found that many Tecra A4 models in fact have Intel GMA chipsets instead of NVIDIA or ATI.